# How to implement OpenID Connect with JWT id_token in Django allauth?

Tags: django, jwt, openid-connect, openid, django-allauth

I use the Allauth plugin for Django. I would like to give the users the possibility of logging in to another provider. This offers OpenID Connect with JWT id_token. Can I solve this with allauth onboard, or do I need my own provider?

The goal is to register with this provider and also login if the user is registered.
With Google, Facebook, ect. This works.

I tried to use the openid_connect provider from allauth, but this is not JWT.